# Move label position in swift with a gesture

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

I have a label in my view controller. I am trying to move the position of the label 50 points to the left every time I tap the label. This is what I have so far but my label won't move in the simulation. I do have constraints on the label. It is about 100 wide and 50 in height, and it is also centered in the view controller.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: gestureLabel, action: #selector(moveLabel))
    gestureLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

func moveLabel(){
    if(left){
        moveLeft()
    }
    else{
        moveRight()
    }

}

func moveLeft(){
    let originalX = gestureLabel.frame.origin.x
    if(originalX < 0){
        bringIntoFrame()
    }
    else{
        gestureLabel.frame.offsetBy(dx: -50, dy: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change the constraint's `constant` property, not the frame.

Comment: In addition to Paulw11's comment, you'll need to create a property for the horizontal constraint so you can do: `horizontal.constant -= 50; view.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: use CGAffileTransform and translate instead of moving center or changing offset. It will be easier. no extra codes will be needed.
and also set: gestureLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 1):

here You can move label where ever You want it

```
 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: self.view)
            print(position.x)
            print(position.y)
            lbl.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:position.x-60,y:position.y-50)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The label wont move because it has constraints. The easiest way to do this is next:

1) create a label programatically (so you can move it freely around)

```
    var labelDinamic =  UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,200, 200));
    labelDinamic.text = "test text";
    self.view.addSubview(labelDinamic);
```

2) set label initial position (i suggest to use the position of your current label that has constraints. also, hide you constraint label, because you dont need it to be displayed)

```
labelDinamic.frame.origin.x = yourLabelWithConstraints.frame.origin.x;
labelDinamic.frame.origin.y = yourLabelWithConstraints.frame.origin.y;
```

3) now you move your label where ever You want with the property

```
labelDinamic.frame.origin.x = 123
labelDinamic.frame.origin.y = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

UILabel's `userInteractionEnabled` is `false` by default. Try setting it to `true`

Answer (score 0):

You should be changing the constraint of the label, not the label itself.

Also, your `target` should be `self`, not `gestureLabel`.

Plus, you could animate that. :)

Like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Centers the Meme horizontally.
    @IBOutlet weak var centerHorizontalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // A custom UIView.
    @IBOutlet weak var okayMeme: OkayMeme!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addGestureRecognizer()
    }

    func addGestureRecognizer() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveMeme))
        okayMeme.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func moveMeme() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            self.centerHorizontalConstraint.constant -= 50
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

"Demo":

[image: DEMO]

Answer (score 0):

You made a new frame, but didn't assign it to the label. `offsetBy` doesn't change the frame in place. It creates a new one.

Replace

```
gestureLabel.frame.offsetBy(dx: -50, dy: 0)
```

with

```
gestureLabel.frame = gestureLabel.frame.offsetBy(dx: -50, dy: 0)
```

But the method above assumes, that you're using directly, not constraints. A standard approach is to have a "Leading to Superview" constraint and change its constant instead of changing the frame.